# Cast object literal to subinterface

Tags: typescript

Take a look at following code: [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20get()%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Smth1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20x%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20value%3A%202%2C%20get()%20%7B%20return%20this.value%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Smth2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20x%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20value%3A%202%2C%20get()%20%7B%20return%20this.value%20%7D%20%7D%20as%20A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Smth3%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20x%3A%20A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20x%20%3D%20%7B%20value%3A%202%2C%20get()%20%7B%20return%20this.value%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) (turn on `noImplicitThis` flag)

```
interface A {
  get(): number;
}

class Smth1 {
  public x: A = { value: 2, get() { return this.value } }
}

class Smth2 {
  public x: A = { value: 2, get() { return this.value } } as A
}

class Smth3 {
  public x: A

  constructor() {
    const x = { value: 2, get() { return this.value } }
    this.x = x
  }
}
```

Both `Smth1` and `Smth2` have compilation errors:

```
public x: A = { value: 2, get() { return this.value } }
```

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'value' does not exist in type 'A'.
>
> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'A'.

```
public x: A = { value: 2, get() { return this.value } } as A
```

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'A'.

Only `Smth3` has no compilation errors.

That means that I must add explicit constructor for my class and split assignment into two statements: temporary variable and assign it to a class field.

As for me, it seems to much code for such thing.

**How can I assign object literal with extra fields as an interface type without using `as any`?**

Answer (score 3):

A way to do this without an extra interface is to use a helper function. This gets around the error that object literals must only specify known properties, but it maintains full type checking on compatibility between `A` and the json literal. :

```
function objectLiteral<T>(v: T) : T{
    return  v;
}

class Smth1 {
    public x: A = objectLiteral({ value: 2, get() { return this.value } })
}
```

You still need to define an extra entity, but at least it's reusable.

**Edit**

A functionless way to do it, would be an extra field/variable, it works pretty much the same way `_x` will be inferred and then checked for compatibility when assigned to `x`:

```
class Smth2 {
    private _x ={ value: 2, get() { return this.value } };
    public x: A = this._x;
}
```

Or without defining the function explicitly, using an self executing function.

```
class Smth2 {
    public x: A = (() => ({ value: 2, get() { return this.value } }))();
}
```

Comment: A better name for that function would be `inferType()`

Comment: @SLaks I guess, I'm not sold on it.. when you mention inference people may expect more then it actually does. Regardless of naming, it helps :)

Comment: But `json` is completely wrong (this cannot even be JSON)

Comment: @SLaks how about `objectLiteral` ? Better ?

Comment: Interesting, but it makes an extra function call in runtime. I would prefer to keep compiled code clean.

Comment: @Qwertiy true, there is an extra call, i added a functionless way, but don't really think it's cleaner

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a separate subtype that has that property, so that TypeScript recognizes your `this` as a type that has the property:

```
interface AWithValue extends A { value: number; }
class Smth2 {
  public x: A = { value: 2, get() { return this.value } } as AWithValue
}
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20get()%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20AWithValue%20extends%20A%20%7B%20value%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Smth4%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20x%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20value%3A%202%2C%20get()%20%7B%20return%20this.value%20%7D%20%7D%20as%20AWithValue%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)